# Set parent id from csv file

Tags: java

I want to set the parent id from csv file in this format (example of country, city and postalcodes)

```
Greece
  Athens
    13561
    10434
Cyprus
  Larnaka
    55477
```

Comment: Please show us the code that you have already written. Also, your CSV file doesn't contain any comma, which sounds weird.

Answer (score -1):

I just want to help others if they have any problem of this kind. The random id is actually the id returned from the database.
If I have a mistake please fix it.

```
public class Record {
private String value;
private int level;
private int parent;
private int id;

public Record(String value, int level) {
    super();
    this.value = value;
    this.level = level;
}

Random rand = new Random();
    ArrayList<Record> records = new ArrayList<Record>();
    records.add(new Record("ελλαδα", 0));
    records.add(new Record("αθηνα", 1));
    records.add(new Record("13561", 2));
    records.add(new Record("1044", 2));
    records.add(new Record("τριπολη", 1));
    records.add(new Record("801456", 2));
    records.add(new Record("501457", 2));
    records.add(new Record("κυπρος", 0));
    records.add(new Record("λαρνακα", 1));
    records.add(new Record("987654", 2));
    records.add(new Record("654321", 2));   

    for(int i =0; i<records.size();i++) {
        if(i==0){
            records.get(i).setId(rand.nextInt(50000));
            records.get(i).setParent(-1);
        }
        if(i > 0){
            int prev_depth = records.get(i-1).getLevel();
            if(records.get(i).getLevel()>prev_depth){
                records.get(i).setParent(records.get(i-1).getId());
                records.get(i).setId(rand.nextInt(50000));
            }else if(records.get(i).getLevel()==prev_depth){
                records.get(i).setId(rand.nextInt(50000));
                records.get(i).setParent(records.get(i-1).getParent());
            }else{
                int ridx = i - 1;
                while ((prev_depth != records.get(i).getLevel()) && (ridx >= 0)){
                    prev_depth = records.get( ridx).getLevel();
                    ridx -= 1;
                }       
                records.get(i).setId(rand.nextInt(50000));
                if(ridx==-1){
                    records.get(i).setParent(-1);
                }else{
                    records.get(i).setParent(records.get(ridx).getId());
                }

            }
        }
    }
    records.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't actually answer your question.  You question is about how to read from a csv file, and your answer is just using random data.